# shell script to process a file and do math on it

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a file with data in this format.
The last column in the file is numeric and I need to sum every 3 records and print average

```
a1;b1;c1;d1;2.70
a1;b1;c1;d1;1.30
a1;b1;c1;d1;3.00
a2;b2;c2;d2;7.30
a2;b2;c2;d2;1.40
a2;b2;c2;d2;2.50
```

The output will look like this

```
a1;b1;c1;d1;2.33
a2;b2;c2;d2;3.73
```

Of course I can write a program to parse each line, tokenize using `;` and then do the math on them.
Or I can export the data to excel and write a macro.
But is it possible to do this is shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be `sed`. It is easier with `awk`:

```
awk -v OFMT="%0.2f" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}!(NR%3){print $1,$2,$3,$4,($NF+sum)/3;sum=0;next}{sum+=$NF}' file
```

- We set the input and output field separator to `;`. We use `awk` built-in variables `FS` and `OFS` for this.
- `!(NR%3)` evaluates to true for every third line. When this is true, we print the entire line up to the last field. We add the last field to our `sum` variable and divide by 3 giving us the average. We reset the `sum` variable to 0 and move to the next line.
- For every other lines we just add the last field to our `sum` variable.
- `OFMT` is another `awk` variable that helps to preserve the format of getting up to 2 decimals.

```
$ cat file
a1;b1;c1;d1;2.70
a1;b1;c1;d1;1.30
a1;b1;c1;d1;3.00
a2;b2;c2;d2;7.30
a2;b2;c2;d2;1.40
a2;b2;c2;d2;2.50
$ awk -v OFMT="%0.2f" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}!(NR%3){print $1,$2,$3,$4,($NF+sum)/3;sum=0;next}{sum+=$NF}' file
a1;b1;c1;d1;2.33
a2;b2;c2;d2;3.73
```

Comment: `OFMT="%0.2f"` can be used to make the decimals upto two decimal places only

Comment: @aelor Thank you! Updated the answer to use that.

Comment: perfect. I just ended up writing a 50 line code in java. But I'm going to use your approach. Can you please add details on your answer so that it would be helpful if I need to make any change

Comment: @arunmoezhi Added the explanation.

Comment: @arunmoezhi Do you not want to do it every 3rd line? You can create an array to compare first three columns and do math on 5th.

Comment: @jaypal:I'm fine with every 3rd line. But if I wanted to change it to say `9` I have to modify this command. But the alternate solution did not depend on the number and was based on quality. So I was just curious.

Comment: @arunmoezhi If you wish to compare first three columns and do math on 5th, then you can do `awk -v OFMT="%0.2f" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{lines[$1 FS $2 FS $3]+=$5;count[$1 FS $2 FS $3]++} END {for (line in lines) print line, lines[line]/count[line]}' file` This will create a key of first three columns which could be present anywhere in the file and not just first n number of rows.

Comment: how do I do it if I have multiple columns to find average. Lets say, I have c1;c2;c3;c4;c5;c6;c7;c8. Where I want to preserve c1 to c4 and find average of c5, c6,c7 and c8

Answer (score 1):

This version does sum based on equality, not on count:

```
awk -F\; '{a[$1FS$2FS$3FS$4]+=$5;b[$1FS$2FS$3FS$4]++} END {for (i in a) print i FS a[i]/b[i]}' file
a2;b2;c2;d2;3.73333
a1;b1;c1;d1;2.33333
```

Comment: can we modify this so that the equality compares only first three columns and ignore 4th column and still do the math on 5th column?

Comment: Yes.  Do you like 1,2,3 not 4, then 5,6,7, not 8, then 9,10,11 not 12 etc. Then add `NR%4` at the start like this `awk -F\; 'NR%4 {a[$1...`  It will just remove every `4th` line

Comment: how do I modify this if I have to sum multiple columns?

Comment: @arunmoezhi Its better if you post a new question with example.

Comment: actually I figured  this out :)